# Eclipse Galileo/Windows/Java memory woes

Tags: eclipse, memory, crash, vmargs

In short, I have 8G of memory and eclipse/java is dying after the splash screen when I try to set the vmargs to something reasonable, like -Xms512m -Xmx2048m.

In long:
I'm running XP Pro x64, v. 2003, SP2.  I'm attempting to use scala with eclipse, and in the interest of being up-to-date, I downloaded a recent Galileo for RCP/Plug-in devs:

> Eclipse Platform
>
> Version:
>   3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB Build id: M20100211-1343

It takes quite a long time even to get past the splash screen to the workspace selection dialog.  This is even before I tried to install scala.

Somewhere over at Scala, I ran across a recommendation to increase the vm memory settings, but using any -Xms setting over 64M causes the splash-and-crash (never mind any -Xmx setting).  My eclipse.ini looks like:

```
> -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
> --launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
> -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
> -showsplash org.eclipse.platform
> -vmargs
> -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
> -Xms64M
> -Xss1M
> -server
> -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
> -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

And I have java 6.0.200.2 installed, with my PATH set to point to it.  I've browsed for hours trying to find a solution...any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 64-bit version of Eclipse and Java.  The 64-bit version of Eclipse will be mainstream with the upcoming release in June, but the current version is rather difficult to find.

You can find it here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5.2-201002111343/index.php

Comment: Thanks...I'm now downloading the 64-bit versions of the JVM and eclipse.  Will let you know...

Comment: I finally got my plugins, eclipse, and java all set up again.  It seems to be working fine (and much faster...)  
Thanks!